# Openshift 3 starter

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

Im trying to investigate how to get a simple SpringBoot project up and running on openshift 3 starter(free version).

Im using this simple starter project whixh uses widfly, see here:
https://github.com/callistaenterprise/spring-boot-openshift

I followed the build/deploy guide here and tried both wildfly and openjdk image types, both fail.

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/02/23/getting-started-with-openshift-java-s2i/

The error in the build console is this:
Pod
blog2-1-build
Failed sync
Error syncing pod

Pod
blog2-1-build
Scheduled  Successfully assigned blog2-1-build to ip-172-31-53-149.ec2.internal

i have no idea how to solve this, any advice help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately Online Starter is having some ongoing issues at the moment. Keep re-triggering the build occasionally to see if it comes good. You can keep track of the status of the cluster at https://status.starter.openshift.com/ This link can be found in top banner of web console, where it should already be showing that there are current issues.

Comment: I retriggered so many times. Now I may consider switching to using AWS :(

Comment: Yes, much more stable these days. Great!